# p-spectrum kernel and weighted all-substrings kernel in R

Tags: r, string

Are there any packages which implement the p-spectrum kernel and weighted all-substrings kernel in R? These are detailed in sections 2.3 and 2.4 of http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.135.938&rep=rep1&type=pdf

If there aren't any packages which already do this, what would be the easiest way to implement both of these methods?

Sorry that this doesn't have any reproducible code, I just want to compute the values for each of these methods given an input of a vector of character strings.

Thanks!